# Creating an SQL query with multiple counts and different criteria from one table

Tags: sql, vb.net, vba, ms-access

I have an Access DB I have coded in VBA which my team use to log all of our requests. I want to create a query which will pull multiple counts from a single table with different criteria. An example of the table follows:

```
    Table TLogging
    logTypeId - Int [ this is 0 - 5 ] 
    isResolved - Boolean [ this is stored as -1 for true, 0 for false ]
```

I want to create a query which will output something like the following:

```
    Resolved, LogType1, LogType2
    True      101       39
    False     49        104
    All       150       144
```

So I want:

```
    Count of LogType1 where isResolved = True
    Count of LogType1 where isResolved = False
    Count of LogType1 where isResolved = True OR isResolved = False
```

And the same for LogType2.

I have already searched SO and other forums, but found no solutions. Also, CASE WHEN does not work in Access VBA.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with something like this:

```
SELECT logTypeId, Count(logTypeId) AS nbTotal, -1 * Sum(isResolved) AS nbTrue, Count(logTypeId) + Sum(isResolved) As nbFalse
FROM TLogging
GROUP BY logTypeId;
```

It gives about the same result as you want, but transposed.

EDIT: or this, it's ugly but i think it gives exactly the result you want

```
SELECT 'True' As Resolved, t0.nb As LogType0, t1.nb As LogType1, t2.nb As LogType2, t3.nb As LogType3, t4.nb As LogType4, t5.nb As LogType5
FROM (Select -1 * Sum(isResolved) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 0)  AS t0
    , (Select -1 * Sum(isResolved) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 1)  AS t1
    , (Select -1 * Sum(isResolved) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 2)  AS t2
    , (Select -1 * Sum(isResolved) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 3)  AS t3
    , (Select -1 * Sum(isResolved) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 4)  AS t4
    , (Select -1 * Sum(isResolved) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 5)  AS t5
Union All
SELECT 'False' As Resolved, t0.nb As LogType0, t1.nb As LogType1, t2.nb As LogType2, t3.nb As LogType3, t4.nb As LogType4, t5.nb As LogType5
FROM (Select Count(*) + Sum(isResolved) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 0)  AS t0
    , (Select Count(*) + Sum(isResolved) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 1)  AS t1
    , (Select Count(*) + Sum(isResolved) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 2)  AS t2
    , (Select Count(*) + Sum(isResolved) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 3)  AS t3
    , (Select Count(*) + Sum(isResolved) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 4)  AS t4
    , (Select Count(*) + Sum(isResolved) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 5)  AS t5
Union All
SELECT 'All' As Resolved, t0.nb As LogType0, t1.nb As LogType1, t2.nb As LogType2, t3.nb As LogType3, t4.nb As LogType4, t5.nb As LogType5
FROM (Select Count(*) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 0)  AS t0
    , (Select Count(*) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 1)  AS t1
    , (Select Count(*) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 2)  AS t2
    , (Select Count(*) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 3)  AS t3
    , (Select Count(*) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 4)  AS t4
    , (Select Count(*) As nb From TLogging Where logTypeId = 5)  AS t5
;
```

Comment: Hi Jean. Thanks for the answer, however this does not satisfy my needs as it is simply putting everything into multiple columns.